# How to fix a problem repeatedly occurred on safari IOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I am getting so annoyed with this problem (A problem repeatedly occurred error message) on ios iphone. Working hard to build a website but only iphone with recent ios versions has this problem. Chrome will load the site on iphone but same problem. It's some ios efficiency issues. Getting rid of css transform and animation didn't solve it for me. My site was designed on adobe xd and I exported it using web export and got some javascript to scale it for any display size. I don't know how the page artboard size was too big like width: 3554px and height: 2346px. Never faced any problem on windows and android. Recently iphone testing made me so disappointed. The javascript isn't causing the problem here even though there is transform scaling involved. I tested an initial version of the website where the javascript scaling didn't cause any problem. Then I cleaned up all animations and css transform. But still same problem. Is this because of big page size like width 3554px ...? Can't safari handle this ...? Please help me to solve it. I don't want visitors from iphone get disappointed on my website. I have some article pages which use css media query with like page width 2358px less than the home page. I don't have iphone but checked on friend's iphone that the article pages load but home page doesn't load. Fun fact I have this thing implemented like when you auto rotate webpage will go to full desktop site. Both home and article pages have same problem. But old ios versions didn't show this problem. If you have an iphone please check the links if you know what is the reason behind this. Thanks in advance everyone ... help needed ...

Home page
https://elomymelo.com/index.html

Article page
https://elomymelo.com/jbl%20flip%206%20meaningful%20upgrade.html

I don't have mac book. So if you got mac on latest os and safari please check it and let me know if there is this problem on mac os or not ...

CSS

```
#Web_1920__1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 3554px;
    height: 2346px;
    border: 0px grey solid;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    overflow: visible;
    --web-view-name: Web 1920 – 1;
    --web-view-id: Web_1920__1;
    --web-scale-to-fit: true;
    --web-scale-to-fit-type: width;
    --web-scale-on-resize: true;
    --web-center-horizontally: true;
    --web-enable-deep-linking: true;
}
```

Those variables are for javascript and they're not causing the mentioned problem in the title ...

Comment: U didn’t mention what problem r u facing…

Comment: the title is the problem. In iphone safari it shows a problem repeatedly occurred. This is the error message and website won't load ...

Answer (score 7):

I've been debugging a similar issue reported by our userbase of individuals experiencing Safari on iOS 15.4.1 / 15.5 crashing with this error message of *"A problem repeatedly occurred"*

After some investigation, I've discovered that the issues likely has to due with iOS/Safari's update to WebGL 2.0 / WebGL for Metal, and issues with CSS `@keyframes` animations.

Specifically in regards to the issue I was experiencing, if there is a **child element** that has a CSS `opacity` rule applied to it within a **parent element** that has a CSS `@keyframes` animation applied to it, Safari would crash after several seconds and display this error.

If I removed the CSS `opacity` styling rule from the child element within this parent element that has the `@keyframes` css animation applied to it, OR if I just removed the css `@keyframes` animation styling rule from the parent element itself, this resolved the issue and the crash no longer occurs.

This issue does **not** appear to affect *iPadOS* 15.4.1, only *iOS* 15.4.1 or greater.

There's definitely some bugs that reside in this latest iOS / Safari update and I believe they are all related to this new WebGL 2.0 / WebGL for Metal integration *(as per similar issues I read about [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-safari-crashes-after-ios-upgrade-to-15-4-1.1269779/) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253191136))*

I have also reported this issue on the [Apple Support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253902820), in hopes that they will address this in a future update.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Haven't been able to solve it yet. Is there any free software I can test my website on ios 15 on safari other than BlueStacks ..?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just ran into this problem today.

If you’re still having the problem I found a weird fix through safari settings.

If you go to IPhone settings > safari settings > Advanced > switch Java script off.

> Go back to whatever webpage it is; it won’t load. > Force close safari > go back to safari settings and switch Java script back on. > the webpage should load on the private safari setting. I have to repeat the steps each time I close the webpage or force stop safari. Really annoying but it’s what I could come up with for now.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of different ways to solve this problem. The root cause of this in my case was the memory taken by my webpage on IOS devices, more specifically the JavaScript Heap size. You can inspect this on browsers by looking into the memory analysis. It shows real time JS Heap size, where you will see the heap size taken by the resources.

I have AdSense ads running on my site. So there is one script tag that is responsible for inserting iframes to show ads. When users scroll and more iframes are present, the heap size increases. Only couple of ads are enough to show the error. So if I block the script for IOS users the JS Heap size decreases by quite a bit, and the error seems to be gone.

So by adding a Content Security Policy, this can be done. The IOS users will see a clean webpage without third-party resources - in my case.

```
   var js,
   fjs = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   var isios = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i)); 
   if(isios) { 
   js = document.createElement("meta");
   js.httpEquiv = "Content-Security-Policy";
   js.content = "script-src 'unsafe-inline'"; 
   fjs.appendChild(js, fjs); }
```

So for some people, it was because of using some graphics heavy CSS properties. But I think, the root was the same - high memory size. Removing animations, CSS or even trying to hide elements out of viewport using IntersectionObserver didn't reduce the heap size quite enough. I had to block that resource, which was inserting iframes - eventually increasing the memory. So reducing the JavaScript Heap size solved my problem.

I am not sure if this issue is still present in latest IOS devices. If anyone knows about this, please share your experience and help each other out. Thanks everybody - good luck.